# How do I merge the results of two ajax (or get) calls with jQuery

Tags: jquery, json

I have a jquery-plugin, which can cope with a function as dataSource

```
var plugin = $element.plugin({
   data: function (callback) {
      // TODO
   }
});
```

It's pretty straight forward, if I only use one dataSource...
But ... I'm in the need of two dataSources

What I've tried so far:

```
var plugin = $element.plugin({
   data: function (callback) {
      var path1 = 'foo1.json';
      var path2 = 'foo2.json';
      var resultOfPath1 = GetContent(path1);
      var resultOfPath2 = GetContent(path2);
      var result = /* this is where i am stuck !! */;
      callback(result);
   }
});

function GetContent(path) {
   // this is where i am stuck!!
   // which method to take? i would like to force a sync. request here
}
```

My two problems with this code:

1. How can I merge two json-lists?
2. How can I force a sync. request (or does anyone have a better idea?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var plugin = $element.plugin({
   data: function (callback) {
      var path1 = 'foo1.json';
      var data1 = {};
      var path2 = 'foo2.json';
      var data2 = {};
      $.getJSON(path1, data1, function (result1) {
         $.getJSON(path2, data2, function (result2) {
            var result = new Array();
            jQuery.each(result1, function (index, element) {
               result.push(element);
            });
            jQuery.each(result2, function (index, element) {
               result.push(element);
            });
            callback(result);
         }
      });
   }
});
```

Comment: +1 for chaining the callbacks, but consider using [concat()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/concat) to merge the arrays instead of `each()` loops.

Comment: @Frédéric: aahhh... did not know about `concat()` - will this work in IE and co either? will this work with objects (as the result of the query will be an json-object)?

Comment: @Andreas, my bad, since you talked about `json-lists` I was assuming you were working with arrays. `concat()` won't work with objects, and the `each()` loops above will merge the values but lose the keys (though it can be fixed). With objects, I'd suggest using [$.extend()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.extend/).

Comment: @Frédéric: as the object is a list, i do not need the keys (these are just the indexes). i do believe that `$.extend()` will merge the objects based on their keys: if the result1 contains key `1`, what will happen with the item of result2 with key `1`?

Comment: @Andreas, it will overwrite the item in `result1`.

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
var plugin = $element.plugin({
   data: function (callback) {
      var 
         paths = ['foo1.json', 'foo2.json'],
         result = [],
         countState = 0;

       $.each(paths, function() {
           var dataSend = {}; //??
           $.getJSON(this, dataSend, function(data) {

              jQuery.each(data, function (i, el) {
                 result.push(el);
              });

              countState++;
              if (countState == paths.length)
                 callback(result); 
           });
       });


   }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

yes ...

have a global variable and push the data you get from ajax.

```
var queue = [];

$.ajax({
url:'blabla',
success:function(data){
  queue += data
}
});
$.ajax({
url:'blabla2',
success:function(data){
  queue += data
}
})
```

Comment: for this solution i need to poll `queue` or introduce a flag-enum to request the state of `queue` (which actions have completed)...